# Differential Equations, stuck after the substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having bit of a trouble solving this differential equation.

$$x^3y'+x^2y-y^2=2x^4$$

I managed to simply by selecting $v=y$ and well up to 
$x^3v'+x^2v-v^2=2x^4$

I got stuck after this when trying to simplify more.

Can someone help me out please?

Rest of the questions in the exercise set look familiar and solutions aren't provided with it.

Comment: what is the point in writing $v$ instead of $y$ if the equation obtained looks exactly same as original equation??? do you really mean $y=v$???

Comment: Divide by $x^3$, it makes it easier to see.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik thats the thing which troubles me as well. I was following steps mentioned in the book but it isn't helping out. Just feels like I'm walking around circles.

Answer (score 6):

I will guide you through a set of hints so you can work it as this is a nice problem.

- Write $y' = \dfrac{y^2}{x^3} - \dfrac{y}{x} + 2x$
- As your book hinted at (I think this is what you meant), let $y = x^3 v$
- This reduces your ODE to $v' = v^2 -\dfrac{4v}{x} + \dfrac{2}{x^2}$
- Let $v = -\dfrac{w'}{w}$
- This reduces the ODE to: $x^2 \dfrac{d^2 w}{dx^2} + 4x w' + 2w = 0$
- We recognize this as  Euler-Cauchy, so let $w = x^m$ and substitue in to the ODE
- This gives us the solution $w = w_1 + w_2 = \dfrac{c_1}{x} + \dfrac{c_2}{x^2}$
- From earlier, we have $v = -\dfrac{w'}{w} = \dfrac{2}{x} - \dfrac{1}{x+c}$
- From earlier we have $y = x^3 v$, we can substitute in $v$ and we get

**Spoiler**

> $y(x) = 2x^2 -\dfrac{x^3}{x+c}$

Comment: @Tharindu: Hopefully, my hints provide enough of detailed guidance as it is very late here and time for bed. Hor over the spolier area for the final result. vRegards

Comment: That is a very nice and detailed hint ;-)

Comment: Great bullets and use of the "spoiler"! +1

Comment: How are you this fine Sunday? It's a very nice autumn day here in Wisconsin!

Comment: Enjoy your nap! Fall color vs. wearing shorts in October...hmmm, I'm thinkin' I belong in CA!